# Force List view mode (exclude Grid Mode) if mobile detected

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, view, list-view

Can somebody advise how to exclude Grid Mode category view on mobile devices? Magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: Please specify magento version

Comment: Magento Community edition 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to **System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes**
2. Add exceptions for **Templates**
3. **Exception has two fields**:

**Matched Expression** - possible values are

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini|Fennec
```

**Value** - Name of the theme in your package.

Lets assume that we set Value to "**mobile**" then your folder structure should look like this:

```
app/design/frontend/your_packege_name/mobile/template/
```

---

Or simply you can modify `list.phtml`

Move `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` to **your theme**

add below code at starting of file

```
$isMobile = Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match(
        Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(),
        $_SERVER
    );
```

and with list condition

```
<?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid' || $isMobile): ?>
```

Comment: Thank you!
One correction: <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid' || $isMobile): ?> instead of <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid' || $ismobile): ?>

Comment: Hello again!
Now I see that this method works in the strange way: sometimes (in random) on desktop computer (non-mobile), product listing displays in a List mode by default, but in a toolbar it shows that a Grid mode selected. 
Please advise

Comment: The only variable is the User Agent, so... When it happens what UA do you have? if it's a mobile UA then there you go.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982828/9499457 for an alternate way to do this without using Design exceptions